# Enabling KSM: Restart of libvirtd necessary?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've just enabled ksm on one of our hypervisors with lots of running VMs (qemu-kvm) that all are using the same operating system. Anyway, pages_sharing and pages_shared both still show 0:

```
root@myserver:~# cat /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run
1
root@myserver:~# cat /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_sharing
0
root@myserver:~# cat /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_shared
0
root@myserver:~# grep KSM /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_KSM=y
```

May I have to restart libvirtd or even restart the virtual machines to see some effect? I already restarted a few similar VMs but pages_sharing and pages_shared are both still 0...
I was hoping to activate the feature without interrupting virtual machines.

Some system infos:

```
root@myserver:~# grep KSM /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_KSM=y

root@myserver:~# uname -a
Linux myserver 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@myserver:~# dpkg --list | grep qemu
ii  qemu-kvm                         1:2.1+dfsg-12+deb8u6         amd64        QEMU Full virtualization on x86 hardware
ii  qemu-system-common               1:2.1+dfsg-12+deb8u6         amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (common files)
ii  qemu-system-x86                  1:2.1+dfsg-12+deb8u6         amd64        QEMU full system emulation binaries (x86)
ii  qemu-utils                       1:2.1+dfsg-12+deb8u6         amd64        QEMU utilities
```

Comment: You should not need to restart anything; KSM takes effect immediately when you set `/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run`. Have you run into a kernel bug? Your kernel does seem to be out of date. As does the rest of the system. Consider updating the kernel or upgrading to Debian stable.

Comment: Yes I know, unfortunately on short-term upgrading the system is not an option due to different reasons.
What I see is that /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_volatile is increasing fast while pages_shared, pages_sharing and even pages_unshared stays on 0.
On a similar hypervisor (slightly newer kernel: 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2) ksm works without any problem but on this machine ksm was enabled right after boot time (and before booting any virtual machine).

Comment: I woluldn't do anything else until you can get the system up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About two days after activating KSM I now see pages_sharing and pages_shared counting up.
Not sure why as no changes have been made to the system since activating KSM.